# Synonym or merge [facebook-ads-api] & [facebook-marketing-api]

Tags: discussion

Facebook use to call their advertising platform API the "Ads API" but they renamed it to "Marketing API" earlier this year.

[[facebook-ads-api]](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/facebook-ads-api) has lots of questions and a better tag info than [[facebook-marketing-api]](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/facebook-marketing-api) which reflects its history.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog notes that for v2.3 that Facebook "recently renamed the Facebook Ads API to the Facebook Marketing API."

Comment: Which do you suggest be syno-merged to which?

Comment: facebook-marketing-api is more official so I suggest facebook-ads-api become a synonym or be merged into facebook-marketing-api. I'm not sure if there's a process of synonym first? I'm also a little unclear what happens to existing Q&As etc on the old tag. Thanks!

Comment: I say make [tag:facebook-ads-api] a sym of [tag:facebook-marketing-api]